# Copy Excel Sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to copy one entire Excel sheet into another Excel sheet of the same workbook, using Java SE and Apache POI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889639/apache-poi-copying-sheets

Comment: @IvanSopov, thank you for the URL, but that question is how to copy sheets between different workbooks, whereas my question is how to copy sheets in the **same** workbook.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll probably want the [cloneSheet(sheetNumber)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#cloneSheet%28int%29) method on the Workbook. See the [JavaDocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#cloneSheet%28int%29) for details

Comment: Thanks! How do I add this returned HSSFSheet object to the workbook?

Comment: You don't have to, it's automatically added for you before it's returned to you

Answer (score 5):

Did you check the API?

to copy a sheet into the **same workbook**, use 
[`HSSFWorkbook.clonesheet(int sheetIndex)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#cloneSheet%28int%29)

Ivan's comment has linked the question for copying across workbooks.

Comment: Thanks! How do I add this returned HSSFSheet object to the workbook?

Answer (score 4):

Yes , this can be...Here my code.

```
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            int totalRecords = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < totalRecords - 1; i++) {
                workbook.cloneSheet(1);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalRecords; i++) {
                workbook.setSheetName(i, "S" + i);
            }
```