# apache poi copy data from one sheet to other in same workbook consumes time

Tags: java, apache-poi

when i have around 4000 records and if i try to copy the data from one sheet to another then it consumes very much time.
However it works fine with 200-500 rows. 
Is there any way to tackle this time issue for copying the data from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the SXSSF API?
https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Comment: I am using HSSF and i export the file as .xls  and the client is using the .xls files for data fetching so i need some way to copy the data from one sheet to another in the same workbook(HSSF Workbook).

Comment: Apache POI is notorious for its memory consumption especially the HSSF. I think they improved it in later versions. But 4000 rows should be doable. Please post an MCVE to get better help.

Comment: @svasa -- Please find the example below:-
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889639/apache-poi-copying-sheets?rq=1**

Comment: I have used the same code @svasa but i when the count is more then the export to excel in case of .xls takes too much time.